# Ignore route in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, routes, laravel-5

I want to create dynamic pages CMS for my Laravel app. Admin is allowed to provide any URI for any page, so for example, he can create page with `one/two/three` URI and http://example.com/one/two/three will point to this site. I already figured out it's possible to add single route for multiple level URLs like this:

```
get('{uri}', 'PageController@view')->where('uri', '.+');
```

Now, I also want to have `/{username}` URLs to point to users profiles. That means, if I need to make it work together. For me, the perfect code would be something like this:

```
get('{username}', 'ProfileController@view');
get('{uri}', 'PageController@view')->where('uri', '.+');
```

Then, in ProfileController I'd like to make my route go further just like it wasn't there. Something like this:

```
// ProfileController

public function view()
{
    $user = User::whereUsername($username)->first();

    if ($user === null) {
        // Go to the next route.
    }
}
```

Can it be done with Laravel?

I can think of another solution, just to have dynamic routing controller for both usernames and page uris mapping, but I would prefer to have it as separate routes.

Comment: I would just add a prefix like `/users` to your `ProfileController` route

Comment: @peaceman I know it would make it easier, but I **really** want to keep /{username} routes.

Comment: Couldn't you generate a php file with all the admin defined routes and include it before the `ProfileController` route? This should also result in a faster routing process.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve a new PageController instance out of the Service Container if `$user` is `null`.

```
// ProfileController

public function view()
{
    $user = User::whereUsername($username)->first();

    if ($user === null) {
        // Go to the next route.
        $params = []; // If your view method on the PageController has any parameters, define them here
        $pageController = app(PageController::class);
        return $pageController->callAction('view', $params)
    }
}
```

This way, the {username} route will stay but will show custom content defined by the admin.

**Edit:**

If you don't want to call a controller manually, you could analyze the current URL segments and check for an existing user before you define your route. In order to not make your `routes.php` file too complex, I'd add a dedicated service class that analyzes your URL segments:

`App\Services\RouteService.php:`

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

class RouteService {

    public static function isUserRoute()
    {
        if(count(Request::segments()) == 1)
            return !! User::whereUsername(Request::segment(1))->first();
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

`routes.php:`

```
<?php

use App\Services\RouteService;

if(RouteService::isUserRoute())
{
    get('{username}', 'ProfileController@view');
}

get('{uri}', 'PageController@view')->where('uri', '.+');
```

I have not tested this, but it should work. Adjust the RouteService class to your needs.

I'm using the first approach in my CMS and it works realy well. The only difference is that I have written a Job that handles all incoming requests and calls the controller actions respectively.

Comment: I think this is not the best idea to call controller from another controller like this. It's not very flexible, I would like to be able to tweak my routes any time. I think it would be perfect if the route hasn't been "matched" if controller action returns null or something.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Hope this is a good solution for you.

Comment: This solution is problematic as well. Using it, I am not able to get route data when being at another route. I skipped this in my example, but I'm calling my routes by names, because it's the most flexible way. Using that "if" statement, my named route won't be defined when I'm somewhere else.

Comment: You really need a custom route handler job for this where you call your controllers manually like in my first solution. I think you will still be very flexible if your route handler is well designed. Another solution would be to rename your profile route so it matches `example.com/@username`, maybe thats an option for you. In the end I cannot think of another solution.